# RESTful way implementing an connection control

Tags: rest

I am implementing a software updating server by REST web service. It is designed to get an client upgrade "instructions" (not the file itself) by GET request to resource

```
/clients/{clientId}/upgrades?completed=false
```

Clients are designed to polls the resource in a 30 minutes interval. The resource returns status code 404 when no upgrades available and return the upgrade instructions if available. When a client upgrading is completed, client will report to server by a PUT request to

```
/clients/{clientId}/upgrades/{upgradeId}
```

with some status change.

Now, an upgrade connection control from server-side is needed, i.e., a maximum simultaneously upgrade connection limit.

I can add a field of "upgrading" status indicator to upgrade resources, change the indicator when /clients/{clientId}/upgrades is accessed, and calculating a "count of upgrades with upgrading==true" to find the connection number. Then return status code 404 to client if connection number limit is exceed. However, it do breaks the stateless principle of REST web service.

Any idea is welcomed. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could require that a client make a successful PUT to the resource with a value requesting to start the upgrade, such as a status of "upgrading". Every time your server gets one of those values it will check the current total of clients it has approved. If there are resources left then it can return success which allows the client to proceed.

When the clients send their completion PUT requests then you can decrement the resource counter.